# Take substring and use it in multiple where condition in sql

Tags: mysql

I have a string which has some values concatenated. Like 'Val1val2val3val4'.

I have a query like
Select * from table where var1 = Val1 and var2 = val2 and var3 = var3;

Val1 and val2 are length only 4 but val3 may differ in length. Val4 is of length 8 and no use.

I can form query with functions like  var1 = substring (text, 1, 4), var2 = substring (text, 5, 8) and for var3 = substring (text, 9, Len(text) - 8).

But the problem is, i have to manually edit replace the value in 3 places in query each time in workbench. Which is a painful task in my case. Is it possible to just put the string in one place and make the SQL automatically take substrings and use in where clause conditions? I have only read access, cannot modify tables. Local variables like @var = Text, throws error code 1046. Hands tied for me. Need ideas if feasible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put the input string into a derived table of one row, and cross-join that to your table:

```
SELECT ...
FROM (SELECT 'Val1val2val3val4' AS text) AS v
CROSS JOIN MyTable
WHERE var1 = substring(v.text, 1, 4) AND ...
```

Or you could use a user-defined variable and use it in a subsequent query:

```
SET @var = 'Val1val2val3val4';

SELECT ...
FROM MyTable
WHERE var1 = substring(@var, 1, 4) AND ...
```

You mentioned you got a 1046 error, but it's not clear how you were trying to assign it, so I can't guess what happened.

Comment: The 2nd option is what I tried and got 1046 database not selected error. After some research, it was the LEN() built-in function causing the problem. Thanks a lot for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that both `@var1` and `@var2` have length of 4 chars, then all you need is:

```
WHERE text LIKE CONCAT(@var1, @var2, @var3, REPEAT('_', 8))
```

If not then:

```
WHERE text LIKE CONCAT(@var1, @var2, @var3, REPEAT('_', 8))
  AND CHAR_LENGTH(@var1) = 4
  AND CHAR_LENGTH(@var2) = 4;
```

If the comparison should be case sensitive, change to:

```
WHERE text LIKE BINARY CONCAT(@var1, @var2, @var3, REPEAT('_', 8))
```

Comment: Can u please elaborate on ur 1 st method. Looks like a short solution. Just not getting how to use it. FYI, i only length of val1, val2 and val4 is 4, 4 and 8. Although all the values will vary in each record.

Comment: @Sivaramakrishnan if @var1='abcd', @var2='efgh' and @var3='qrstuv' then the condition is: `WHERE text LIKE 'abcdrfghqrstuv________'` which means that text should start with `'abcdrfghqrstuv` and after that should have 8 more chars (any chars). Simple as that.